# How to host an ASP.NET Web API that is composed of multiple projects in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, rest, iis, asp.net-web-api, hosting

I am new to ASP.NET Web API and to RESTful services in general. I recently started working in a Web API that was already started by another developer that is no longer in the company, and **the approach that he used for making this API was to create a new project for every Resource that the API exposes**. My question is, **what is the correct way to host this API in IIS?**  I can create a new Website in IIS manager for each project, but then I will have many sites. Also, for testing purposes I tried creating just one Website in IIS and then adding an Application within the Web Site for each service that have to be deployed, and this also works, the problem is that for each project (resource) a virtual directory is created and then the route to access the Resource includes the virtual directory name and I don’t want this, because then the routes will look like this:

BaseURL/**VirtualDirectory** /api/resource

I have googled for examples on how to host an ASP.NET Web API in IIS, but all the posts that I have found show how to host a single service project, and not an API that is composed of multiple projects. So, I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please paste a few screen shots. It is not clear what it looks like in your VS solution explorer and in IIS Manager.

Comment: URLrewrite can be used to integrate mutiple URL  in some case. But we need to know how your project works. If you don't want to create mutiple websites or webapp, then you have to integrate your project to make it return result based on different parameters. Besides, host mutiple websites is just a normal.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description , I guess you want the url should now show the vitual directory.

E.g:
`VirtualDirectoryName.yourdomain.com/api/resource` to `www.yourdomain.com/VirtualDirectory/api/resource`.

If this is your requirement, I suggest you could try to use url rewrite extension to achieve your reuqirement.

You could dirctly download it from below url:
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Then you could use below rewrtite rule into the web.config.

```
<rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.+).sample1.com" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.sample1.com/{C:1}" />
</rule>
```